# Creating a controller that can control the intensity of emission of smoke

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rigging, smoke-simulation

I have been trying to create a rig that can control the intensity of emission of condensation (similar to smoke) on wings like the one in the video (at 1:33)
https://youtu.be/wjTV2AdoLNs?si=JqxRDM6sgNThumlZ

He just rotated the controller and boom ! The condensation appears
[image: notice how he just rotated the controller marked in red]
[image]

Up until now I have been able to just create a vapour condensation without volumetric using displace modifier with coordinates set to an empty which gives an effect of motion of condensation when moved around (when the empty is moved around)

However I am not able to create an effective rig as shown in the video above, ie control the size of the condensation , and also animate the motion of the condensation** (vapour or smoke or whatever they call it).

I will leave my progress below

[image: viewport]
[image: modifier]
[image: texture properties]

Comment: Why am I not getting any help ??

Comment: [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)